# Alpha value of SWT.graphics.color doenst work

Tags: java, colors, swt, transparent, alpha

Good morning,

I have a problem with the colors I want to use in my application.
I have created a dialog using SWT and I want it to have a coloured border.
To decide, which color the border should have, a value is set.
If the value is 0, the border should be transparent / without color, if the value is 1, the border should be blue. I have defined both the colors and blue works fine, but the transparent color just gets black when I open the dialog.

> Color transp = new Color(device, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
>   Color blue = new Color(device, 0, 0, 255, 255);

Do someone know what could be going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I created two colors, a blue one and a transparent one as you can see above. I want to create a border around my dialog with one of these colors using "e.gc.setForeground(color);". This works in general, but when i put my transp color in here, its black instead of transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when the alpha value is set separately.

```
                e.gc.setForeground(color);
                e.gc.setAlpha(color.getAlpha());
```

Comment: Dear Don, if you think your answer is correct and works, you should mark your answer as correct answer to help others finding better answer quickly.